# mac install ruby failed. Error running '__rvm_make -j4'

Tags: ruby, macos, cocoapods, rvm

when I executed "rvm install 2.7.2" in the terminal, I got the Error running '__rvm_make -j4',If anyone can help, I would appreciate it

Comment: related issue ticket about macOS 13.1 ventura: https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/5287#issuecomment-1367598523

Answer (score 1):

using macOS BigSur had the same problem, this worked for me:

```
CFLAGS="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration" rvm install x.x.x
```

Comment: Sadly it does not work on Ventura (13.4.1 (22F82)), M1 :(

Answer (score 1):

This helped for me: https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/5043#issuecomment-967000943

Copy below:

1. Right click Terminal from the Application/Utilities folder, Get Info, tick the "Open using Rosetta" box.
2. Uninstall Homebrew

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall.sh)"
rm -rf /opt/homebrew/*
sudo rm -rf /opt/homebrew
```

3. Reinstall Homebrew

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

4. Restart terminal
5. Check Homebrew is working fine: `brew doctor`
6. Reinstall openssl: `brew install openssl`
7. Install Ruby: `rvm install 2.7` Or any version

Comment: Sadly it does not work on Ventura (13.4.1 (22F82)), M1  :(